# optimal solution is found in AMPL IPOPT while the constraint is not satisfied

Tags: optimization, constraints, ampl, ipopt

I am trying to solve this simple optimization question including gel functions

```
 function gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Qinv;
 var x1 >= 0 ;
 minimize obj: (x1^2)-8*x1;
 subject to const1: x1-4 <= gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Qinv(1- 0.05);
```

Then I tried to solve this in AMPL

```
 ampl: model test.mod;
 ampl: load amplgsl.dll;
 ampl: option solver ipopt;
 ampl: solve;

 EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 Ipopt 3.12.4: Optimal Solution Found
 ampl: display x1;
 x1 = 3.99996
 subject to const1:
-gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Qinv(0.95) + x1 <= 4;
 ampl: display -gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Qinv(0.95) + x1;
-gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Qinv(0.95) + x1 = 5.64481
```

As it is obvious, the constraint is not satisfied! I wonder why and how I can fix this.

Thanks,

Mahraz

Answer (score 0):

it seems that by loading library first and then loading the model, this issue would be solved.

```
ampl: model test.mod;
ampl: load amplgsl.dll
```